# How do I install Visual Studio 2015 after it's been installed on a missing drive?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I realise that my title doesn't make much sense, so allow me to elaborate.

I had Visual Studio Community 2015 on an external hard drive (F:). This drive recently had some bad sectors and I removed the drive, replacing it with an internal drive (E:). Now, when I try to run the Visual Studio Community 2015 installer, it comes up with Modify, Repair and Uninstall buttons, as if it was already installed. None of the options work; they all get so far and then the installer encounters an error.

I've tried removing all visual studio instances from the registry with regedit and that didn't work. I've also tried running the installer as admin with "/uninstall /force" command line.

Here is the bottom of the log file when I try to uninstall: http://pastebin.com/NsGF29ea

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you're in for a fresh installation...

Comment: I assume drive F: is the old drive that's no longer attached. I wonder if you used VeraCrypt or something to create a virtual disk partition, and mount it as F: just to get rid of the invalid drive error?

Comment: Use Disk Manager (built into Windows) to change your disk drive letter from E: to F.  You can re-order any drive letters you want; internal drives don't have to be first alphabetically. If you used the same directory/path, you might get lucky enough to get it to work.

Comment: @jessehouwing I wanna avoid reinstalling windows if possible (I assume that's what you are suggesting)

Comment: @SteveKennedy I would do that, but I have other programs that are installed on E:, so that would create problems with them.

Comment: I looked at your log file. I bet if you mount an F drive (to anything valid, like a USB drive) and then try the uninstall again, it will work.

Comment: @SteveKennedy This is strange, when I use Disk Manager to mount it to F, it says that the parameter is incorrect.

Comment: That seems like a completely different problem.  I think the trick here is to get your computer to think it has a VALID F drive.  It doesn't necessarily have to look like your E drive, or have anything on it.  Make sure that whatever you mount as your F drive is readable by Windows normally.  You might have to restart to get this to happen. That should cause your log file to get passed the error it's stating now -which is "invalid F drive".  Once you fix that, you *might* be able to re-install/repair/uninstall. But not sure.

Comment: @SteveKennedy Thanks, putting a blank flash drive onto F: worked for me.

Comment: Awesome, i summarized the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use Disk Manager (built into Windows) to change your disk drive letter from E: to F.  You can re-order any drive letters you want; internal drives don't have to be first alphabetically. If you used the same directory/path, you might get lucky enough to get it to work. I looked at your log file. I bet if you mount an F drive (to anything valid, like a USB drive) and then try the uninstall again, it will work. I think the trick here is to get your computer to think it has a VALID F drive.  It doesn't necessarily have to look like your E drive, or have anything on it.  Make sure that whatever you mount as your F drive is readable by Windows normally.  You might have to restart to get this to happen. That should cause your log file to get passed the error it's stating now -which is "invalid F drive".  Once you fix that, you *might* be able to re-install/repair/uninstall. But not sure.

Comment: Let me know if his helped/answered.